# Action by automorphism group of a ring $R$ on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, schemes, quotient-spaces, automorphism-group

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $G\subset \mathrm{Aut}(R)$ be a subgroup of the automorphism group. Then $G$ also induces an action on the affine scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. Namely, for $g:R\to R$ an element in $G$, the action of $g$ on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is just the isomorphism
$$
\mathrm{Spec}(R)\to \mathrm{Spec}(R), \mathfrak p \to g^{-1}\mathfrak p
$$

Let's simply consider the case $G=\mathrm{Aut}(R)$. Then,

**Question:** What should be the quotient $\mathrm{Spec}(R) /\mathrm{Aut}(R)$? Is there any interesting structure on this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a general fact that for a group $G$ acting on an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} R$, we have that the quotient is given by the spectrum of the ring of invariants $R^G$. So the key is to figure out what $R^G$ is.

Determining what $R^{Aut(R)}$ seems to be a bit iffy, though - I had previously made an incorrect guess here, and don't see how to determine this in general for all suitable commutative rings.

Comment: Your guess in the last paragraph isn't right. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ (as a ring) has no nontrivial automorphisms.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Good point, I didn't think of that. I have edited the post to say that I don't see a general method of computing $R^{Aut(R)}$. If you have any insight, I'd enjoy hearing about it!